# mod_rewrite subfolder to subdomain without redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this URL http://sub.domain.com/index.php and I'm trying to map/point http://domain.com/folder/index.php to the file on the subdomain without redirect

I want both urls to point to the same PHP file.

This does it with a redirect, which is not what I'm trying

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule   ^folder/index.php$  http://sub.domain.com/index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are `http://domain.com/folder/index.php` same as `http://sub.domain.com/folder/index.php` ?

Comment: I'm trying to link to the same file.

This URL is the only one working at the moment
http://sub.domain.com/folder/index.php

this url need to point to the above link without redirecting to it
http://domain.com/folder/index.php

Comment: But isn't `sub.domain.com/folder/index.php` same as `domain.com/folder/index.php`?

Comment: No it's  http://domain.com/folder/index.php and  http://sub. domain.com/index.php. it's 2 different urls

Comment: But what URL do you want to show in the browser?

Comment: I want to show this url domain.com/folder/index.php
but I want the above url to be rewritten to this sub.domain.com/folder/index.php

Comment: It is still not clear and you're not going to get any answer like this. What is DocumentRoot for both main domain sub domain. I need to get more info about your directory structure.

Comment: Okay sorry for all the confusing.

this folder "/var/www/domain.com/folder" is this URL: http://sub.domain.com/index.php. It's outside my public_html


In my public_html folder:  "/var/www/domain.com/public_html" is this URL: http://domain.com/folder/index.php


Today I use this url: http://sub.domain.com/index.php, and I want the index.php file to be available at this URL as well http://domain.com/folder/index.php. So I have 2 URLs to the same php  file. I can copy the index.php file to that location but then I have to manage 2 files, that's why I want it mod_rewrite so I stay at one php file

Comment: If `DocumentRoot` of `domain.com` is `/var/www/domain.com/public_html` then **it cannot access any files/directories above this path** hence `/var/www/domain.com/folder` is out of bound for `domain.com`.